# Polymorphic association with many belongs to one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

I'm having this subscription table and this subscription table can have_many orders, and can have_many appointments.

I was trying to create an polymorphic association so that subscription.subscribables should give all the orders and appointments associated with this subscription.

How to achieve this?

I tried adding polymorphic association at subscription table but later I got stuck

Comment: Why would you need it as an association? Since they are in 2 different tables (presumably), then joining them and almost everything else you would want to do on a relation can't work anyway.

Have you considered just a method called subscribables that would query them both and add them together?

Alternatively use a union as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57493688/4473406 though that is still probably not the right approach.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.